# How to align div of different sizes next to and directly above each other?

Tags: html, css

I managed to align them using float but some aren't directly above each other. I have tried a lot of methods but it doesn't seem to work but some of the elements have different width, and some things that do align align further away. Here is the css code: https://codepen.io/Filizof/pen/vvGqJb?editors=1100

```
float: right;
width: 900px;
```

Only showing these two because they seem to be the fix but also the problem.

Comment: Please post your code here!

Comment: There are 110 lines of code, stack doesn't allow you to copy and paste you have to put everything in manually and create the spaces at the front

Comment: You probably saw `{}` symbol. There is another symbol `<>` which is specially for HTML, JS and CSS where you can copy the code easily. Click on `edit` and you will see the symbol in the edit box menu.

Comment: You can try CSS Flexbox (Flexible Box) - W3Schools
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
.conversions {
  width: 800px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the grid to make it easy. The only you might have to do, it´s create new divs to put inside the stuff you already created.

I hope it will be helpfull for you.

```css
body{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "one two"
                         "three three";
}

.one{
    grid-area: one;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.two{
    grid-area: two;
    background-color:green;
}

.three{
    grid-area: three;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="one">
        one
    </div>
    
    <div class="two">
        two
    </div>
    
    <div class="three">
        Three
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```